# How to mount a snapshot from boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using boto 2.5.1, Python 2.7, Ubuntu Precise.  I want to mount a snapshot on an EC2 instance.  I've gotten as far as creating a volume from the snapshot, but then I can't figure out how to attach it.  If I do:

```
[setup stuff elided]
c = EC2Connection()
print volume
print instance
c.attach_volume(volume, instance, "/dev/snap")
```

I get the amazingly unhelpful exception:

```
vol-2df00677
i-1509d364
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mongo_pulldown.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "./mongo_pulldown.py", line 28, in main
    c.attach_volume(volume, instance, "/dev/snap")
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 1530, in attach_volume
    return self.get_status('AttachVolume', params, verb='POST')
  File "/home/roy/deploy/current/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 985, in get_status
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

with no clue of what I've done wrong.  I'm assuming the device name is arbitrary, and the attach call will create the device as part of the process?  Or does the device have the exist already?

How can I get some more useful diagnostic than just "Bad Request"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attach_volume` method takes an `instance_id` and a `volume_id` but you are passing objects.  Try this:

```
c.attach_volume(volume.id, instance.id, "/dev/sdh")
```

The `device_name` should be a reasonable device name for the OS you are using.  You can find more about what that value should be [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html).

boto uses standard Python logging so you can configure it to log as much or as little as you want.  This [gist](https://gist.github.com/garnaat/1539859) shows a shortcut approach to get full debug logging.  However, boto can only log what it has access to and it's possible the response from EC2 just doesn't provide much information.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I am passing strings, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that I was passing something bad for device.  I was passing '/dev/snap'.  When I changed that to 'xvdg', things worked.  It appears that '/dev/xvdg' also works (and has the same effect; the '/dev/' part appears to be ignored).

I wrote a little function to find the next available unused device name:

```
def get_device_name():
    for c in 'fghijklmnop':
        name = "xvd%s" % c
        path = "/dev/%s" % name
        try:
            os.stat(path)
        except OSError:
            return path
```

I was hoping that by using a fixed name outside of the set that's normally used, I could avoid having to worry about this silliness.